# Content of public function of a plugin inside function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Is it possible to grab the content of a public function inside a plugin in my child theme? If yes, how to do it?

This is the code of a plugin (simplified)

```
final class DM_Reviews {

    public function review_breakdown() {
        echo '<div class="reviews_breakdown">';
        $this->display_total_reviews_count();
        echo '</div>';
    }    

    public function display_total_reviews_count() {
        echo '<div class="reviews-total-count">' . $this->count_reviews() . '</div>';
    }

    public function count_reviews() {
        global $wpdb, $post;

        $count = $wpdb->get_var(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                "
                SELECT COUNT(meta_value)
                FROM {$wpdb->commentmeta}
                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->comments} ON {$wpdb->commentmeta}.comment_id = {$wpdb->comments}.comment_ID
                WHERE meta_key = 'dm_rating'
                AND comment_post_ID = %d
                AND comment_approved = '1'
                AND meta_value > 0
                ",
                $post->ID
            )
        );

        return $count;
    }

}
```

I'd like to copy this part inside my theme

```
echo '<div class="reviews_breakdown">';
        $this->display_total_reviews_count();
echo '</div>';
```

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Comment: If I copied it as it is, there's an error because of `$this->` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you could just create a separate function and place it in functions.php:

```
function my_count_reviews() {
    global $wpdb, $post;

    $count = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "
            SELECT COUNT(meta_value)
            FROM {$wpdb->commentmeta}
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->comments} ON {$wpdb->commentmeta}.comment_id = {$wpdb->comments}.comment_ID
            WHERE meta_key = 'dm_rating'
            AND comment_post_ID = %d
            AND comment_approved = '1'
            AND meta_value > 0
            ",
            $post->ID
        )
    );

    return $count;
}
```

and then just call that function

```
echo '<div class="reviews_breakdown">';
echo my_count_reviews();
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: So copying the entire function is the only solution then. I was hoping there would be an easier way.

Comment: try  echo DM_Reviews::count_reviews(); but funciton should be public static to work this way and on some versions of php that might not work.

Comment: It works. Thank you. Do you perhaps know on which php versions it wouldn't work?

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately I do not remember exactly, some versions are more strict to OOP standards. You need to look into php documentation and see where you can use public functions without being declared as static outside of the class or without instantiating an object. If you can modify the function just make it public static and your're safe